# How to use Jadeify with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gulp, browserify

First off, my ultimate goal is to be able to use `jade` templates with `backbone` But this is the best solution I could come up with.

**browserify.gulp**

```
//appoligies for including it all.
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var bundler = browserify({
        // Required watchify args
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true,
        // Specify the entry point of your app
        entries: ['./src/site/js/app.js'],
        // Add file extentions to make optional in your requires
        extensions: ['.js'],
        // Enable source maps!
        debug: true
    });

    var bundle = function () {
        // Log when bundling starts
        bundleLogger.start();

        return bundler
            .transform(require('jadeify'))
            .bundle()
            // Report compile errors
            .on('error', handleErrors)
            // Use vinyl-source-stream to make the
            // stream gulp compatible. Specifiy the
            // desired output filename here.
            .pipe(source('main.js'))
            // Specify the output destination
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
            // Log when bundling completes!
            .on('end', bundleLogger.end);
    };

    if (global.isWatching) {
        bundler = watchify(bundler);
        // Rebundle with watchify on changes.
        bundler.on('update', bundle);
    }

    return bundle();
});
```

**Jade.gulp**

```
gulp.task('jade', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/site/views/*.jade')
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/templates'));
});
```

**app.js**

```
//the main angular file
var jamie = require("../views/resultsMini.jade");
console.info(jamie);

//outputs: 
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};
    var jade_interp;

    buf.push("<div>Results List</div>");;return buf.join("");
}
```

So the real quesiton is, why does `jamie` not return me the html? I assume I've just done it completely wrong :(

Is there some usage I am missing here? From the docs: https://github.com/domenic/jadeify

```
var template = require("./template.jade");

document.getElementById("my-thing").innerHTML = template({
    localVar: "value",
    anotherOne: "another value"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Jadeify with Gulp in Backbone like this

Here is my browserify task:

Please note there is absolutely NO reference to Jadeify in this task at all. I'm just showing you the task to demonstrate it clearly.

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var browserify    = require('browserify');
var source          = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify    = require('browserify');
var gulpif          = require('gulp-if');
var connect         = require('gulp-connect');
var streamify     = require('gulp-streamify');
var uglify          = require('gulp-uglify');

var watchify      = require('watchify');
var bundleLogger  = require('../util/bundleLogger');
var handleErrors  = require('../util/handleErrors');
var strip         = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var print         = require("gulp-print");
var datapaths     = require("./datapaths");

gulp.task('js', ['environmentCheck'], function() {

  console.log('GULP: Starting js task');

  var bundler = browserify({
    // Required watchify args
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true,
    // Browserify Options
    entries:    ['./core/js/core.js'],
    extensions: ['.coffee', '.hbs'],
    debug:      global.ENV === 'development'
  });

  var bundle = function() 
  {
    bundleLogger.start();

    return bundler
      .bundle()
      .on('error', handleErrors)
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      // remove console.logs and such
      .pipe(gulpif( global.ENV === 'production', streamify( strip() )))
      // uglify JS and obfuscate in produciton mode only
      .pipe(gulpif( global.ENV === 'production', streamify(uglify({ mangle: global.ENV === 'production' }))))
      .pipe(print())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(global.outputDir + datapaths.dataPath + '/js'))
      // .pipe(connect.reload())
      .on('end', bundleLogger.end);
  };

  // if(global.isWatching) {
  //   bundler = watchify(bundler);
  //   bundler.on('update', bundle);
  // }

  return bundle();
});

gulp.task('js_prod', ['setProduction'], function() 
{
  gulp.start('js');
});
```

In my package.json I have the Jadeify transform applied.

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "jadeify"
  ]
},
```

My Backbone view wich imports the template directly form the jade file, no strings attached (the transform in the package.json takes care of the rest)

```
var tag_item_template = require("../../../../../jade/templates/itemviews/tag_item_template.jade");

App.Views.TagView = Marionette.ItemView.extend(
{
    model: models.getTagModel(),
    template: tag_item_template,

    templateHelpers: function()
    {
        return {
            i18n_tag:           i18n.getI18NString('tag'),
            title:              functions.getModelValueSafely(this.model, 'title'),
        }
    },

    ui: {
        'titleInput':       '.input-title',
    },

    events: {
        'click .interact-delete':   'kill',
        'click .interact-save':     'save',
        'keyup .form-input':        'catchEnter'
    },

    catchEnter: function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode === 13) // enter key
        {
            this.save();
        }
    },

    onShow: function()
    {
        console.log('TagView ::: onShow');
    },

    save: function()
    {
        console.log('TagView ::: save');

        var new_title           = this.ui.titleInput.val();

        this.model.set('title', new_title);

        functions.saveModel(this.model);
    },

    kill: function()
    {
        functions.destroyModel(this.model);
    },
});
```

Then the JADE template for you to see the variables that are being passed in by the "templateHelpers" function of the Backbone view:

```
include ../mixins

div.focus-area-element.list-element.single-list-item
    div.inner-content
        div.list-item-actions.absolute-position
            +ui-icon-button('ok', 'fontello', 'save', 'success')
            +ui-icon-button('cancel', 'fontello', 'delete', 'error')

        +ui-icon-list-item('tag', 'ui8')

        +ui-input('text', i18n_tag, title, 'title', true)
```

Comment: You lovely lovely man!!!! `"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "jadeify"
  ]
},` this got it working for me

Comment: Yes the transforms can be applied via either the package.json file or via JavaScript. Doing it via JavaScript like you did is the best way to go. It allows to add options more easily, and avoids messing with the package.json file. I have changed my gulp tasks to be that way too.

Answer (score 3):

`var jamie = require("../views/resultsMini.jade");`

`jamie` is now a function which accepts locals as arguments and will return html when called

compare the output of
`console.info(jamie)` to `console.info(jamie({property: 'value'}))`

Comment: Although oddly this still hasn't fixed my problem :)